# Demonstrate that A=B

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to demonstrate that $A=B$ in these cases:
$$A= \{ x\, |\, x = 5n + 2\wedge n \in\mathbb{Z} \}$$

$$B= \{ x \,|\, x = 5k - 3 \wedge k \in\mathbb{Z} \}$$

Answer (score 3):

- Let $x\in A$.
- So it should be like $x=5n+2$ for some integers $n$.
- So $x=5n+2=5n+(5-3)=5(n+1)-3=5k-3$ and $n+1=k\in\mathbb Z$.

$~~~~~\Large{\therefore}$

$~~~A\subseteq B$.

Do the same way to show that the converse is also true.

Comment: $+1\ddot\smile!$

Answer (score 2):

Just prove that $A\subset B$ and also $A\supset B$